# rsync diff but with filter on certain file extension only

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

I am trying to perform diff on sub-directories that includes certain file extension only.

Below is my folder structure

```
GRADES
  --test1
      --file1.pdf
      --file2.pdf
  --test2
       -T60_Hello.xml
  file123.pdf
  T60_Hello.xml
  T61_Hello.xml 
 --test3 (this folder would contain everything except files with extension .xml)
```

What i want to do is when i perform diff from GRADES (src) to Test3(dest) then i want to include only files with following filter - `T60_*.xml`

Below is my script -

```
rsync -rvcm --include='T60_*.xml' /Users/Desktop/GRADES/* /Users/Desktop/GRADES/test3
```

At the moment i am getting all files that are not in Test3 folder.

Comment: Which files do you want to compare / diff exactly? everything from GRADE against everything from GRADE/test2 with a T60_*.xml pattern, and store outputs in GRADE/test3 ??

Comment: `... --include='T60_*.xml' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ...`

Comment: @Jhnc your solution worked including T60_*xml file and all T60 xmls within directories and excluding everything else